# Open round screw in computer case

Tags: screws

Unable to open these round screws in my desktop case. Please tell me what these screws are called and how to open them.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the manual for the case.  They typically have a list of screws and a description.  Without knowing more about the case it won’t be possible to identify that screw (if it’s even a screw)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a key lock to me. You need the key.
They're not 'special' as in they're all about the same, so you could probably buy another. You can get ones that are actually 'keyed' with a set of indentations so they're all different, but that one looks simple. More of a deterrent than an actually secure lock.

You could very probably twist it with needle-nosed pliers, but note: use cheap ones, you are never meant to twist that way with delicate pliers.

Similar found on [AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32544422561.html) & many others…

[image]

This is a more secure version. Note the indentations, circled.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### Please tell me what these screws are called and how to open them.

That appears to be a [Computer Case Screw Lock](https://www.google.com/search?q=computer+case+screw+loc).

You will have to find a key that matches the lock.

Examples:

[image]

[image]